# Code compiled on Mac OS 10.7.5, gcc 4.2.1 doesn't compile on Linux, gcc 4.3.4. Error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped

Tags: linux, macos, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

I have written a C++ code on my Mac (OS 10.7.5) and have successfully been running it for some time.  It runs very slowly, so I want to parallelize it on a Linux-based cluster.  The first step is to upload the code at the cluster and then compile and run it as a test (no parallelization).

When I do "make," I am getting this error:

> collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core
>   dumped

From searching online, it seems to be related to the compiler.  So far, I haven't found an explanation of how to deal with it that doesn't involve reinstalling things related to the compiler.  I don't have the ability to install anything on the cluster.  I'm a newbie as far as dealing with compilers.  I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

1. When I do "gcc -v" at the cluster, here's what I get:

> Using built-in specs. Target: x86_64-suse-linux Configured with:
>   ../configure --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/info
>   --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.3 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --with-bugurl=http://bugs.opensuse.org/ --with-pkgversion='SUSE Linux' --disable-libgcj --disable-libmudflap --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --program-suffix=-4.3 --enable-linux-futex --without-system-libunwind --with-cpu=generic --build=x86_64-suse-linux Thread model: posix gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux)

1. When I do "gcc -v" at my Mac, this is what I get:

> gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build
>   2336.11.00)

Comment: Run `make clean` and try again. Your GCC is really too old. Current GCC is 4.8.1; BTW, you could (with some pain) compile a recent GCC (e.g. thru `.../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=$HOME/pub --program-suffix=-4.8` ....) on your cluster without root privilege....

Comment: Thanks for your help, Basile.  I have tried make clean, but I have the same problem.  Are you saying that the problem is that GCC is too old on the cluster?

Comment: Perhaps your cluster GCC is too old. And certainly, it is obsolete: newer GCC generate better code & diagnostics, are more standard conformant, so are recommended for HPC software.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  If you can think of any fixes that would not require me to install anything on the cluster, I would be very grateful to hear about them.  As far as trying your previous suggestion, would this install a new GCC in my home?  Please excuse the dumb question, but how would I specify that I want to use it in my makefile?

Comment: You take time to configure and build a GCC in your home, then you add e.g. `$HOME/pub/bin` to your `$PATH` and the newer GCC would be installed in `$HOME/pub/bin/gcc-4.8` etc... If possible, ask help from your cluster sysadmin. (You could spend a day or two on this).

Comment: Maybe you might need a newer binutils (i.e. `ld` linker).

Comment: I saw that term when I was searching online about this error, but I don't understand it.  So you're saying there's a linker separate from the compiler?  And that it might need to be updated?